# Save two values from firebase database for offline use

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have `ProfileActivity` where users get access to `CollegeActivity` if `name` value in the Firebase Realtime Database of that user is `Jhon` and `permission` value is `yes`. This is my database structure.

```
Users
 |-name: "Jhon"
 |-userID
    |-permission: "yes"
```

It works fine when it is connected to the internet. But how can I store both the `name` value and the `permission` value as cache that if the user is offline, `ProfileActivity` can look into the cache and give access to `CollegeActivity` if the last session met the condition?

This is my `ProfileActivity`:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ref.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String identityCheck = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                if (identityCheck.equals("Jhon")) {
                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);
                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String userpermission = dataSnapshot.child("college").getValue().toString();
                            if (userpermission.equals("yes")) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, CollegeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence?

Comment: Also: please don't leave your `onCancelled` methods empty as you're bound to miss important errors that way. The minimal implementation could be `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
throw databaseError.toException();
                        }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the response and the doc. But I'm wondering if I persist this `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").setPersistenceEnabled(true);`, would it store all the users data locally? If yes, is there any security concern of being the data of other users being exposed?

Comment: The client will never persist anything that it isn't allowed to read. But `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` is a global call that enables the disk cache. You don't call it on a specific `DatabaseReference`. Give it a try!

Comment: there is a 10mb size limit on the local data

Comment: Oh! I got it. Really appreciate the help. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score -1):

You can either use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#GetSharedPreferences) on first access, or [firebase's native caching mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence), or a simple file or sqlite (room for easier sqllite cursor access). There are various ways to cache values for persistence depending on your data size and app requirements.